# Make a Bar Chart on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, charts

I'm new to iPhone and I want to make a rectangle portion to show coordinate. It's just like one bar, when you change the value in options and the percentage of the bar change too. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use [UIProgressView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) or [Google chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).

Answer (score 0):

CGRect CGRectMake(
    float x,
    float y,
    float width,
    float height
)

x & y are fixed width and height depends on your bar-orientation , calculate the length of the bar on yourself

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [DSBarChart](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/). A simple Objective-C Bar Chart / Histogram library.

And here is the [sample usage](http://dhilipsiva.com/DSBarChart/#sample-usage)

It is exactly what you want.